# Default selection option

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form with action as select option between urls.  The code is as follow :

```
<form id = "idForm"
      name "Formname"
      action=""
      method ="GET">
 <select type="hidden" name ="cat" onChange="changeAction(this)">
      <option value="0" selected="selected"  search-url = "url1"> URL1 </option>
      <option value="1" search-url = "url2> URL2 </option>
 </select>
```

and the script :

```
function changeAction(obj) {
        var url = obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].getAttribute('search-url');
        document.FormName.action = url; 
    }
```

The change action works fine, my issue is that when I first go to the page, there default url is not URL1, when I type a query string and submit, the url is like this :

`website/?cat=0&q=string and not website/url1/?cat=9&q=string`

It just after I switch between the two options is that url is correctly formatted for both options.

I hope i have made myself clear. Apparently the selected option is not working and i tried it both on firefox and google chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are simply forgettig a double quote for the search-url attribute of the second option.

```html
<form id = "idForm"
      name "Formname"
      action=""
      method ="GET">
 <select id="myselect" type="hidden" name ="cat" onChange="changeAction(this)">
      <option value="0" selected="selected"  search-url = "url1"> URL1 </option>
      <option value="1" search-url = "url2"> URL2 </option>
 </select>
```

If you are getting issues at the first call, I mean, when you open the website by first time you should implement a `ìnitialize` method or something like that.

```
function changeAction(obj) {
    var url = obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].getAttribute('search-url');
    document.FormName.action = url; 
}

function init(){

    var e = document.getElementById("myselect");

    // you could do this way....
    var str_select = e.options[e.selectedIndex].getAttribute('search-url');
    document.FormName.action = str_select;

   // ... or even simpler
   changeAction(e);


}
init();
```

Comment: Ah no that's just a typo.

Comment: ok! If you already know what is your default selected option, why not set the form action with its `search-url` ?

Comment: Should `init();` be not after function definition?

Comment: exactly ;), did you understand this approach??

Comment: Thank you, that works and you explication was very clear. I didn't know about the init() function.

Comment: A side question, is there a way to hide option values when we submit the form so it shows only :   website/url/?q=query and not  website/url/?cat=value&q=query

Comment: try changing `GET` by `POST` in your method attribute.

Comment: Please, take into account that the `ìnit` method is a resource that we have invented to solve the problem. You could name it whatever you want, but I called `init` because it's task is initialize the form attributes. But it's not a JS function, ok?

Answer (score 0):

Action will be set onChange. You are required to trigger event on page load to select Url1 so that changeAction() will be called and set action to Url1.